# Undo checkout is giving exception

Tags: 2011, core-service

Below is my code for checking if a page is checked out using core service. My code is running with MTS user. I have checked out the page and the condition is getting evaluated to true but once the execution reached `client.UndoCheckout()` method call, it is giving an exception stating

> Item is not checked-out

I went back and checked in CME and the page was still checked out. Am I missing something, because this is very weird?

```
try
{
  PageData pageData = client.TryCheckOut("tcm:18-8339-64", new ReadOptions()) as PageData;
  if (((pageData.VersionInfo) as FullVersionInfo).LockType == LockType.CheckedOut)
  {
    client.UndoCheckOut(pageData.Id, false, null);
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Console.write("ERROR:"+ex.Message); 
}
```

Update:

I have even tried below and getting the same exception.

```
if (!pageData.IsEditable.Value)
{
  client.UndoCheckOut(pageData.Id,true,null);
}
```

Comment: Can you add a check to print out the AllowedActions to the console? What are these values?

Answer (score 2):

It might be transaction problem, for debug, try to wait for a second or two before doing UndoCheckOut.

May I ask you why are you trying to do this? You can read the page and check `LockType` if it's CheckedOut, or if you want to check if current user can checkeout item you can take a look at `AllowedActions`

Comment: Updated the code

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code should work. its strange you are getting the error.

a question:

If you are doing un-do check out for the page, why are you checking out using `TryCheckOut`? Because in this case

```
if (((pageData.VersionInfo) as FullVersionInfo).LockType == LockType.CheckedOut)
```

it will always return to true.

I think you should use `Read` to read the page. And then un-do checkout if it is already checked out.

please try below code:

```
        PageData pageData = tridionClient.Read("tcm:tcm:18-8339-64", new ReadOptions()) as PageData;

        if (((pageData.VersionInfo) as FullVersionInfo).LockType == LockType.CheckedOut)
        {
            tridionClient.UndoCheckOut(pageData.Id, false, null);
        }
```